# How to convert 1,000 results from loop function into array of numbers

Tags: python, loops

I have run a loop to execute a simple formula with descending exponent. It looks like the numbers came out right but I cannot do anything with the results form. I wish it was an array with `1,000` float numbers.

```
m = 1000
for x in range (m):
    y = m - x
    alpha_hat = 1 - ((1 - alpha)**(1 / y))
    print (alpha_hat)
```

Would like to see an array of `1,000` results from the defined formula.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
m = 1000
results = [1 - ((1 - alpha)**(1 / (m - x))) for x in range (m)]
```

**EDIT:**
This solution is much cleaner and more efficient than appending:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
answer = []  # creates an empty list

m = 1000
for x in range (m):
    y = m - x
    alpha_hat = 1 - ((1 - alpha)**(1 / y))
    answer.append(alpha_hat)  # adds your alpha_hat to the list we created

print(answer)  # or don't
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution would be to store in a list:

```py
alpha = 0.5
m = 1000

def make_hats(m):
    alpha_hats = []
    for x in range(m):
        y = m - x
        alpha_hat = 1 - ((1 - alpha)**(1 / y))
        alpha_hats.append(alpha_hat)
    return alpha_hats

print(make_hats(m))
```

Answer (score 0):

Learn list comprehention in Python

```
answer = [1 - ((1 - alpha)**(1 / (m-x))) for x in range(m))]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need array and not list you have to use NumPy.

```
import numpy as np

alpha = 0.5
l = list()
m = 1000
for x in range (m):
    y = m - x
    alpha_hat = 1 - ((1 - alpha)**(1 / y))
    l.append(alpha_hat)
array = np.array(l)
print (array)
```

Answer (score 0):

As a loop, like this. I assumed a list is OK to use as an "array". The other answer points out that Python doesn't have type called `array`

```
alpha = .5    # Just did this to make it run
m = 1000
array = []
for x in range (m):
    y = m - x
    alpha_hat = 1 - ((1 - alpha)**(1 / y))
    array.append(alpha_hat)
```

A concise but maybe less readable way using list comprehensions

```
alpha = .5    # Just did this to make it run
m = 1000
array=[1 - ((1 - alpha)**(1 / (m-x))) for x in range(m)]
```

Comment: Thank you, Deepstop, for your two solutions. This is super-helpful.